# Get handle of back  click in java class

Tags: java, android

In my android application my Home activity calls Async task which is placed in another java class.If the user press on back of device i would like to perform some action in async task called.How can i get access of user back click in my java class which doesnot extend Activity.

Please let me know if any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Sorry, just reread your post, didn't realise it was in another Java class, does it extend Activity?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // Code here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: No it does not extend Activity.:(

Answer (score 0):

Override onPause() lifecycle method of the HomeActivity.
It is called when user presses back button.

Comment: onPause() will be called every time when screen will move to background , not necessarily on back press . so not a right choice

Answer (score 0):

You should override [onBackPressed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29), then use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to signal your Async task about the event.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
  your_code(){}

  super.onBackPressed();
  return;
}
```